# Ionic TypeError: invalid data

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I try to run any ionic command, I get the same error:

```
ionic serve
or
ionic info
or
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

Always the same error:

```
TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:704:11)
    at process.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic:9:63)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at emitPendingUnhandledRejections (internal/process/promises.js:108:22)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:124:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Comment: In another project on the same machine, "ionic serve" shows some warnings, but runs OK.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I restored a backup of the project folder and now I can run Ionic without problems.